# How to pass a cutom navOptions during testing

Tags: android, testing, navigation, mockito, fragment

I have a custom animation that I pass during navigation in my fragments, How can I pass a navOptions to navigation during testing.
Here is my custom navOption

```
fun Fragment.customNavAnimation(): NavOptions.Builder {
val navBuilder: NavOptions.Builder = NavOptions.Builder()
navBuilder.setEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_right).setExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_left)
    .setPopEnterAnim(R.anim.slide_in_left).setPopExitAnim(R.anim.slide_out_right)
return navBuilder
```

Here is how I passed it

```
  ui.loginBtn.setOnClickListener {
        findNavController().navigate(R.id.loginFragment, null, customNavAnimation().build())
    }
```

Here is my test

```
  @Test
fun clickCreateAccountButton_NavigateToSignUpFragment(){
    //creates a mock of the navController class
    val navController = Mockito.mock(NavController::class.java)


    //launch fragment
    launchFragmentInHiltContainer<LandingFragment> {
        //assign a new navController to this fragment
        Navigation.setViewNavController(requireView(), navController)
    }
    //click on create account button
    Espresso.onView(withId(R.id.create_account_btn))
        .perform(ViewActions.click())

    //verify if navController was called
    Mockito.verify(navController).navigate(R.id.registerFragment, null, null  )

}
```

when I pass in null as navOptions I get this error

> Argument(s) are different! Wanted:
> navController.navigate(
> 2131362353,
> null,
> null
> );
> -> at com.plentahub.breezcoins_android.ui.LandingFragmentTest.clickCreateAccountButton_NavigateToSignUpFragment(LandingFragmentTest.kt:51)
> Actual invocation has different arguments:
> navController.navigate(
> 2131362353,
> null,
> androidx.navigation.NavOptions@369fdd89
> );

My problem now is how to pass in the custom navOptions